# 'Slice' string in Groovy with step

Tags: python, groovy

Is there a way to slice a string in Groovy by step? Like we do in Python.

Example:

```
>>> name = "Daniella"
>>> name[1:7:1] #start:end:step
'aniell'
>>> name[1:7:2]
'ail'
```

In Groovy:

```
groovy>name = "Daniella"
groovy>name[1..7]
'aniella'
```

Is there a step option here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Groovy, there isn't a special slice syntax; `name[1..7]` is just [subscripting](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#Collections-Slicingwiththesubscriptoperator) with a [range](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#Collections-Ranges).

And, as you can see, ranges don't have a way to define steps.

So, there's no equivalent to the Python syntax here; you'll need to do a bit more work.

One option is to use the `List.step` method on a range:

```
(1..7).step(2)
```

… or even `step` directly on the start number:

```
1.step(7, 2)
```

Another option is to apply an elementwise operation to a range:

```
(1..14)*.div(2)
```

And there are probably half a dozen other ways to do it, but none of them are quite as trivial as what you can do in Python.

Comment: By the way, I haven't used Groovy in years, so it's possible that my knowledge is out of date and there's a better way to do it. If so, someone let me know and I'll delete this.